# Sending NSUserNotification from everywhere

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

In my product, I want to be able to send notifications (NSUserNotification) from everywhere (even from the daemons and so on)

So, I decided to create a Agent that will be responsible for showing notification.
here is plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com /DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.aaa.aaa.notifications_agent</string>

<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/aa/aaa.app/Contents/MacOs/aaa</string>
    <string>--showNotification</string>
    <string>1</string>
</array>

<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/aaa/aaa.app/Contents/MacOs</string>

<!-- Start when we got new data -->
<key>WatchPaths</key>
<array>
    <string>/var/run/notification.sock</string>
</array>
```

The only problem is that it is not working =)
Everything **works** fine when I run the agent manually (from console) and **does not work** when the agent is run by launchd when the file content is changed.

Is is generally possible to show notifications from agent?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the plist. Are you programmatically terminating the agent after showing the notification?

Comment: no I dont. And itt works fine running this exacutable as an programm (from console), not as an agent. Are you sure it is possible to send notifications from agents?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure because I have an agent that has no problems posting notifications. When you run your app from the console, you have to Ctrl+C to quit it, right? Well, if launchd launches your agent, the agent will continue to run. The next time launchd notices changes in the watched paths and tries to launch your agent, it will note that the agent is already running and will give up. You won't receive any notifications after the first one. In your agent, call `[NSApp terminate:self]` after delivering the notification. Do this and you'll get notifications every time there are changes.

Comment: I am sure the launchd launches my agent (I added the logging to syslog). The problem is that is launches the app but dont show notification. Callback is not executed as well

Comment: What did you find at the end?